# Differnce between storing images in RMS or in package

Tags: java-me, rms

I am new to J2ME development, so i am having some problems regarding storing images in RMS.

What is the diffrence between storing image in a package and storing it in RMS, is it the same thing or having any difference. Moreover, if i store image on RMS, then ultimately i would i have to keep it in package too so it consumes space at two different places.

Please help me out with this issue and assist me with the best approach to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMS is used to store data that needs to be loaded again later, like e.g. variables that is input by the user, or highscores achieved in a game.

In my opinion it would only make sense to store images in RMS, if they have been edited by the user. But even then, I'd probably go with saving them on the file-system instead.

A MIDlet cannot come with data pre-defined in RMS. In order to put data into RMS, you need to get that data from somewhere first, e.g. inside the jar file resources folder, or downloaded from the web.